# Trying to find a short story about an undead mother

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I remember reading a short story from the perspective of a child about a farmer's wife, their mother, who dies.  For some reason the farmer is opposed to the normal burial custom in the town (I think it was to cut off the hands, feet, and head of the corpse) and the corpse is not processed fast enough so it starts rising at night and killing people.  There's a scene where the child tries to talk to her mom but the undead mother person leaves or otherwise doesn't murder the kid and some kind of talking happens.  I can't find the story anymore, though.